# Getting access token in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, powerbi, access-token

I'm currently in the process of converting my Power BI embedded application from .NET to .NET core.

My old code for generating tokens looked something like this:

```
var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password);
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);
var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(ResourceUrl, _applicationId).Result;
```

However, by design .NET Core does not support `UserPasswordCredential`.
Gunnar Peipman in a recent article ["Embedded Power BI reports with ASP.NET Core"](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-power-bi-embedded/) used a HTTP request to solve this, but is this the recommended approach?

```
private async Task<string> GetPowerBIAccessToken(PowerBISettings powerBISettings)
{
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var form = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        form["grant_type"] = "password";
        form["resource"] = powerBISettings.ResourceUrl;
        form["username"] = powerBISettings.UserName;
        form["password"] = powerBISettings.Password;
        form["client_id"] = powerBISettings.ApplicationId.ToString();
        form["client_secret"] = powerBISettings.ApplicationSecret;
        form["scope"] = "openid";

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        using (var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(form))
        using (var response = await client.PostAsync(powerBISettings.AuthorityUrl, formContent))
        {
            var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonBody = JObject.Parse(body); 

            var errorToken = jsonBody.SelectToken("error");
            if(errorToken != null)
            {
                throw new Exception(errorToken.Value<string>());
            }

            return jsonBody.SelectToken("access_token").Value<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the [recommended approach](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/482#issuecomment-262256236) is to use `ClientCredential` class.

> The idea here is that for apps to collect and store a user's username and password is not the correct approach for non-interactive authentication.

Also see [Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) and [Acquiring Tokens](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-Tokens):

> Confidential client applications the flows will rather:
>
> Acquire token for the application itself, not for a user, using client credentials.

[And one more quote](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-Tokens#pattern-to-acquire-tokens-in-msal-3x):

> **Pattern to acquire tokens in MSAL 3.x**
>
> All the Acquire Token methods in MSAL 3.x have the following pattern:
>
> - from the application, you call the AcquireTokenXXX method corresponding to the flow you want to use, passing the mandatory parameters for this flow (in general flow)
> - this returns a command builder, on which you can add optional parameters using .WithYYY methods
> - then you call ExecuteAsync() to get your authentication result.
>
> Here is the pattern:

```
    AuthenticationResult result = app.AcquireTokenXXX(mandatory-parameters)
     .WithYYYParameter(optional-parameter)
     .ExecuteAsync();
```

An [example](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-bearer-token/) (again by Gunnar) how to do this:

```
public async Task<AuthenticationResult> RequestTokenAsync(
    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal,
    string authorizationCode,
    string redirectUri,
    string resource)
{
    try
    {
        var userId = claimsPrincipal.GetObjectIdentifierValue();
        var issuerValue = claimsPrincipal.GetIssuerValue();
        var authenticationContext = await CreateAuthenticationContext(claimsPrincipal)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
            authorizationCode,
            new Uri(redirectUri),
            new ClientCredential(_adOptions.ClientId, _adOptions.ClientSecret),
            resource)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
 
        return authenticationResult;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can successfully return a token using `context.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret))`. However, when i try to call the PowerBI client with it, it fails with an 'Unauthorized' error. Any idea what it could be? Do I need to make any changes to my Azure App?

Comment: Check how to setup service principal